# excel conditional formatting reference depending on cell-value

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have two sheets on my xls-document. I want to add conditional formatting to my second sheet. The conditional formatting should be depending on the frist sheet. But there is no fix cell i can reference. The cell which should be referenced in my formular should depend on a value which can be entered by the user.

First sheet:
[image: first sheet]

The row `A` functions like an index. The rows `D`, `E` and `F` could be filled with anything. But they can also be empty.

Second sheet:
[image]

The row `A` tells me ony which row from the first sheet my conditional formatting should refer. The rows `B`, `C` and `D` should be formatted like this:

If the column `D` with the index `1` of my first  sheet has a value, all rows on my second sheet with the index `1` should color red if the column `A` is empty. If the column `D` with the index `1` of my first shett has no value, all rows on my second sheet with the index `1` should color red if the column `A` is not empty.

I know how to reference cells from another sheet and how to color the cell red. But i dont know how to make it depend on the index (column `A`).

VB is not allowed. Only conditional formatting. Can you guys help me?

Comment: It seems that the function `Indirect` can help you.

Comment: As far as I know, indirect can adress sheets or cells by their name as string. But i dont know how this should help me, or am i missing something?

Comment: Idirect didn't seem to help, i was able to solve my problem by using the vlookup-function. Look at my answere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem with the VLOOKUP-function.

```
VLOOKUP(A4;Firstsheet!$A$4:$F$14704;4;FALSE)
```

This looksup the given area on my first sheet (second parameter) and searches for the index (first parameter). When the index is found, it returns the fourth column of the found row (thrid parameter). I dont know what the fourth parameter does.

This just returns the value from the indexed cell from my first sheet. I was able to use this to solve my problem.

Her is the whole formular for Secondsheet.B4:

```
=AND(NOT(ISEMPTY(A4));OR(AND(NOT(ISEMPTY(B4));ISEMPTY(VLOOKUP(A4;Firstsheet!$A$4:$F$14704;4;FALSE)));AND(ISEMPTY(B4);NOT(ISEMPTY(VLOOKUP(A4;Firstsheet!$A$4:$F$14704;4;FALSE))))))
```